# How to get button's id on redircted page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button which is redirecting on a http handler file.

I want to get the button's id which is redirecting.

The button is on a modal pop-up.

Html:-

```
<form action="abc.ashx" method="post">
   // popup
</form>
```

Its the form which is actually redirecting to handler file.

Comment: uh.. what you have tried..? and, why don't you pass the button's id via query string for instance..?

Comment: `Response.Redirect(String.Format("abc.ashx?ID={0}",someValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what the form contains. But you have this:

```
<form action="abc.ashx" method="post">
   // popup
</form>
```

I assume that what you are after is a way in `abc.ashx.cs` to know which button was clicked in the form.

One way is to use `<input type="submit" ... />` like this:

```
<form action="abc.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="foo" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" value="bar" name="bar" />
</form>
```

Then in the `abc.ashx.cs` file you can check:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Form["foo"] == "foo")
    {
        // the foo button was clicked
    }
    if (context.Request.Form["bar"] == "bar")
    {
        // the bar button was clicked
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can try:

```
<form action="abc.ashx" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="foo" name="submitter" />
    <input type="submit" value="bar" name="submitter" />
</form>
```

And:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Form["submitter"] == "foo")
    {
        // the foo button was clicked
    }
    if (context.Request.Form["submitter"] == "bar")
    {
        // the bar button was clicked
    }
}
```

**Note about vocabulary**: If I've understood this correctly, we are not really talking about a redirect here. This is just posting to a different address than the one where the form was loaded. A redirect is when you post/get a certain address and the server sends a redirect response which causes your browser to get a different address.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question doesn't explain what you needed exactly, I'm assuming you want to pass some data from your `.aspx` to your handler page.

You can do it like here..

```
HttpContext.Current["ID"] = data;
Server.Transfer("abc.ashx");
```

And in handler page:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var data = context["ID"];
    ...
```

If call will be made from client side then you need to pass data as `query string` parameter - such as

`Response.Redirect(String.Format("abc.ashx?ID={0}",someValue)`

And use it in handler page as

```
context.Request["ID"].
```